# Calculate Duration

Tags: java, android, time, duration

I have a small android problem, I have a requirement to have a timer to calculate the duration from the time a specific activity was open till a certain button in that activity is clicked, simply how long the activity was open. While googling around I found TimerTask but this seems to run a thread for a certain interval only though and doesent seem ideal for the job from my little Android experience

Any idea on how to calculate the duration? Preferably in a very simple manner

Any help is very welcome

Regards,
MilindaD

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) to capture the time when the activity starts and stops. E.g.:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// wait for activity here
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long seconds = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
```

Comment: This gives seconds, is there any way that I can get `minutes`, `hours` and `days`?

I don't mean the divide by 60 method. Looking for a better solution that that. Is something available?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava - Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html.  It gives some nice formatting to date ranges/durations

Answer (score 13):

As of Java 8 there is more convenient way of doing this.

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
...
Duration.between(start, Instant.now())
```

Benefit of this approach is more flexible API provided by the Duration class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out how long activity is open.

You can write respective code in

- > onCreate() method and onDestory()
  >   method.
  >   or

> - onResume() method onPause() method.

depending on your need.

and make use of following code

```
long t1 =  new Date().getTime();
long  t2 = new Date().getTime();
long t3 =  t2 - t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

group: 'org.apache.commons',name: 'commons-lang3'

```
 StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
 stopWatch.start();
       ...
 stopWatch.stop();
 stopWatch.getTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```