# Time calculate and compare for best time in Android

Tags: java, android

How to calculate time taken in playing a game in Android using java. Can you please specify which timer you are using?
And how to compare those time slacks taken by user to find which is his best score?

Comment: Try to googling first. After, that ask here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562550/calculate-duration

Comment: @SpK Thanks for Your huge help, i didn't know about that.

Comment: @Thelper you get it wrong man. i want to compare those time slacks he is taking to complete that activity..

Comment: There is no need to edit your titles to add "Android:" prefixes to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `System.currentTimeMillis();` to find the current time then start it in a varible and when game finish again call this method and subtract your varible value

```
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime();
```

This  will give you time calculation now to find out best time you have to create separate best time methods for user and cpu like you did for user. so you can compare time easily.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit vague... I am assuming that you want the time taken for the user to complete a game or any other activity... that being said, you could use the `System.currentTimeMillis()` like so:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime(); //Duration in milliseconds
```

Comment: @jave yeah i want the time taken by user to complete that game or activity and i also want to compare all of those time slacks taken by user to to complete that activity and show which one was his best. may be you get it now.

Comment: btw this is helpful to find the time taken by user to complete it.. so thanks. now i have to compare these time slacks..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks by using @npinti 's answer it is very easy to find the time taken by user now here i am putting my logic how did i compare those time slacks.

```
    public String userCompareTime(double cur_Time)
{
    double temp=0;
    if(temp == userBest_Time)
    {
        userBest_Time=cur_Time;
        temp+=1;
    }
    if(userBest_Time > cur_Time)
    {
        userBest_Time = cur_Time;
    }
    return String.valueOf(userBest_Time);
}
```